# Putting different output of r together

Tags: r

I put my result in external folder ("C:\Users\Documents\output") and there are many outputs in that folder and within a single output, I have the following text result:

```
ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean : 38.2334
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     : 48.73024

 Best model: ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean
```

how can I put them in a single file text file using R?

I have used the following code and I get an error:

```
data_dir <- "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Output"      
file_list <- list.files(path=data_dir, pattern="*.txt")                              
data <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file_list, function(x) read.table(paste(data_dir, x, sep=''), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

and I have got the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :

 Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

Comment: use `list.files` to identify all text files. Then use `read.lines` to read the files and `paste` to put them all together.

Comment: @Cettt, thank you very much for the hint and I will try it!

Comment: It's because you don't have a trailing \ on your data_dir. You don't need to paste together you can just set `full.names = TRUE` inside of the list.files. If you want to paste, set `sep = '\\'`

Comment: @at80, thank you very much, but I am still getting the same error and can you put the syntax, please?

Comment: The error is because the path of your files are not correct. When you `paste(data_dir, x, sep='')` its going to look like "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Outputyourfilename.txt". You need to specify the correct path. The best way to fix this is get rid of your paste and use `list.files(path=data_dir, pattern='*.txt', full.names = TRUE')` which should give you the full path so you can replace `paste(data_dir, x, sep='')` with `x`.

Comment: It gives me no error but the output is not in the output folder, the output folder is empty and I don't know why?